# Unit testing Android with Maven

Tags: android, unit-testing, maven

I have a question about a android project that is build with Maven,
We made it run our activity tests, but now we need it to run unit tests.
The unit test is in the same project as the activity tests, how do i set it up in our pom.xml files?

This is the Parent Pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>andersen.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>Hello-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Hello - Parent</name>

  <modules>
    <module>HelloWorld</module>
    <module>HelloWorldTest</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
  <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

this is the application pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>andersen.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hello-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>andersen.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>apk</packaging>
  <name>HelloWorld - Application</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
          <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
          <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
          <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
          <sdk>
            <platform>4</platform>
          </sdk>
          <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
          <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
        </configuration>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and this is the test pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>andersen.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>Hello-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>andersen.project</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworldtest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>apk</packaging>
  <name>HalloWorld - Integration tests</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>andersen.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
      <type>apk</type>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>andersen.project</groupId>
      <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
      <type>jar</type>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
          <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
          <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
          <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
          <sdk>
            <platform>4</platform>
          </sdk>
          <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
          <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
        </configuration>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Should i add the following text in the parent pom.xml?:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

And add it to other poms?

when i run maven the output is:

Junit.framework does not exist

Comment: Of course if you are using JUnit you have to add the dependency.

Comment: Yes but it still fail's. Junit.framework does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [Surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) to the test pom.xml. Surefire runs the unit tests.

Comment: I have added the dependency to the parent pom.xml file and to the test pom.xml file. But it still fail: junit.framework does not exist

Comment: @Casper: Don't forget to add unit tests to the module: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html

Comment: Please post the whole error message. Who says that? Surefire? The Java compiler?

Comment: The consol write it after I did a "mvn clean install" in my parent folder. It succes the build of parent and app, but fails test, with junit.framework.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same problem. It was caused by misconfiguration in the parent pom. You have to remove the scope tag in the dependencyManagement section.

Like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: There exists a TEST scope for maven as well! http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope.