# Testing my maven library compatibility with Android

Tags: java, android, maven, unit-testing, junit

**TL;DR**

I have a Java project that I build and test with maven. What it the simplest way to run my junit tests on an Android sdk?

**More details**

After a commit, a user open a bug report to explain that I broke the compatibility with android since I introduced a dependency on `javax.xml.bind` and this package doesn't exist on Android.

Now I managed to implement my feature without using this package, and I'd like to be sure I don't break this compatibility anymore. Consequently I'd like to run my existing junit4 tests on the Android Sdk. The issue is that I'm an Android noob, and I'm starting to drown under documentations:

- would using [local unit tests](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html) fit my needs?
- If yes, may I use them with maven or shall I switch to gradle first? (ie:  the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html) explains how to do it using Gradle. Is it a prerequisite, or is it possible to do it with my existing build system?)
- Or must I go through the burden of using [instrumented unit tests](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html)? (Are those even usable given that there's no notion of UI at all in my project?)

Comment: Interesting question, actually. I can answer 1) Yes. Android Studio will keep track, that you're not using APIs your are not allow to use due to API level `minSdkVersion` limitations of the lib. 3) Unless you want to test activities and some complicated end-to-end UI(fragments, intents, etc.) scenarios - you're good to use JUnit tests.  I didn't fully understand 2nd question. Can you expand its description(explain your idea)? (I'm not that much familiar with maven, unfortunately)

Comment: Thanks for this information. I just edited my 2nd question. Said differently: As far as I understand, Gradle is described as a "successor" of Maven. In particular, http://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests.html#run is explaining how to build and test with Gradle. If absolutely needed I could change my build system. On the other hand, is it possible to do what I want using eg the maven-android-plugin (http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/index.html)?

Comment: ["people say"(C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231686/unit-testing-android-with-maven) that it's possible and requires [Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/), though it looks ancient and not particularly easy to set up. So if I were you, I'd go for Gradle. But if costs of it is too high - well. It's doable with maven too.

Comment: Thanks for this pointer!

Comment: you're more than welcome. I hope, you'll manage it! (and actually it might be an interesting experience to share somewhere in a blog afterwards). So far, I've converted our dialog into an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. *Android Plug-in for Gradle* keeps track, that you're not using APIs your are not allow to use due to API level minSdkVersion limitations of the lib. (I'm pretty sure, it also archivable with *maven-android-plugin*)
2. It's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231686/unit-testing-android-with-maven) and requires [Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/). I haven't try it personally, unfortunately, so I can just say that from what I briefly read - it looks ancient and not particularly easy to set up. So if I were you, I'd go for Gradle. But if costs of it is too high - well. It's doable with maven too.
3. Unless you want to test activities and some complicated end-to-end UI(fragments, intents, etc.) scenarios - you're good to use JUnit tests. And even if you do need something Android's Activity/Fragment-related, you can use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org) lib for it (it's a unit test framework, allows to avoid instrumented tests in many cases)